# Documentation review - Invalid state

Tags: bug, documentation, review-queues

I have run into an issue when reviewing a proposed change where it says it cannot be approved because it is in an invalid state. If this is the case shouldn't it be rejected by the system automatically and not sent to the review queue?

[Review](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/71178)

[image]

Comment: See the last comment